# FBO depth buffer is red

Tags: java, opengl, fbo, shadows

I can't get my shadow system work properly.
I use the following code to generate my FBO:

```
int frameBuffer = GL30.glGenFramebuffers();
GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
GL11.glDrawBuffer(GL11.GL_NONE);
GL11.glReadBuffer(GL11.GL_NONE);

int texture = GL11.glGenTextures();
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL14.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0,
GL11.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL11.GL_FLOAT, (ByteBuffer) null);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GL32.glFramebufferTexture(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, texture, 0);

GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth(), Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight());
```

My entities are rendering fine in my default renderer (output vec4).
My shadow shader code is straight forward:

```
#version 430
layout(location = 0) out float fragmentdepth;

void main(void){
    fragmentdepth =  gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

I tried to output a vec4(1.0) without using any FBOs and it all worked fine so my calculations are correct and my shader codes should work as well.

My draw call looks like this:

```
GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
renderShadows();
GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
renderAllItems();
Display.sync(FPS_CAP);
Display.update();
GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
GL11.glClearColor(0.2f,0.1f,0.1f , 1f);
```

when I call "renderAllItems();" I am also rendering a quad at the top right corner which should display my depth texture. But all I see is a red quad. 
Shouldn't it be black/white and show something?

Comment: "I can't get my shadow system work properly." -> "I can't get my shadow system to work properly."

Comment: The depth buffer is not any color, it stores depth. It's a single component though and that can be interpreted as any color you want.. which usually does tend to become the red channel.

Comment: "*Shouldn't it be black/white and show something?*" Do you render it as "black/white"?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. But how can I tell my program to render black/white ? just output a vec4(color.r,color.r,color.r,1.0) ? And yes I know that it stores depth. I just used colors to show that my shaders work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> GL32.glFramebufferTexture(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, texture, 0);
> ```

This attaches a texture to the depth attachment of a framebuffer object.

> ```
> layout(location = 0) out float fragmentdepth;
> ```

That is a [user-defined output from a fragment shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Output_buffers). User-defined outputs are mapped to fragment colors, [which get written](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Draw_color_buffers) to *color attachments* of FBOs, not to depth attachments.

The fragment's depth is what gets written to depth attachments. And in an FS, that's the [built-in `gl_FragDepth` output](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Other_outputs). However, there's no reason for you to write to it. If you don't write to it, then it will automatically be filled in by `gl_FragCoord.z`.

Indeed, if all you want is to render depth, you [shouldn't even have a fragment shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Optional).

Comment: Do you have a spec reference for this behavior when rendering without a fragment shader? The only thing I found is that "If there is no active program for the vertex or fragment shader stages, the results of vertex and/or fragment processing will be undefined". Since `gl_FragDepth` is a result of fragment processing, this doesn't tell me that it would be defined in this case.

Comment: OMG it works !!! :) Thank you, Nico Bolas. I just deleted all my content in my fragment shader and changed the displaying texture to show black/white. Thank you very much !! :)

Comment: @RetoKoradi: "*Since `gl_FragDepth` is a result of fragment processing*" That doesn't matter because: "If the active fragment shader does not statically assign a value to `gl_FragDepth`, then the depth value generated during rasterization is used by subsequent stages of the pipeline." If there is no fragment shader, then it cannot assign to `gl_FragDepth`. And therefore, the depth value generated during rasterization is used.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Plus, there's this: "Fragment shaders determine color values for fragments, and may also modify or replace their assigned depth values." Notice how it does not say that the FS "determines" the depth value, only that it *may* "modify or replace" it.